# Create listview that can scroll in both directions

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a listview that can scroll both vertically and horizontally. My problem right now is that i can make the listview scroll horizontally but to a fixed width. Ideally i want the width to be the least possible and I won't know ahead of time the width of the elements in the listview so i want it to be dynamic. Right now it's my width is set to 1000 which is what I'm trying to get around.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 1000,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,"),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use a SingleChildScrollView for both directions and for the vertical direction use a column instead of a ListView.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemExtent: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                      "Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,"),
                ]),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that worsen performance? Since the items of the column will eventually be retrieved from APIs and could potentially be a huge number, i wouldn't want to load all at once. This approach is perfect for me I'm just a little concerned about performance.

Comment: yes, you're right performance would be an issue if there are many items. Look the edited answer. I've added an horizontalScroll to each item. Hope it helps!

Comment: I appreciate the effort my man but I've already tried that and it doesn't serve my purpose since I want the entire screen to scroll horizontally. Would really appreciate if you have any more ideas!